# How to separate a getline from file in to string and integers. C++

Tags: c++, string, integer, ifstream

So i have a .txt file that goes like this:

John F. Bush 35

James Bush 69

(And so on....)

And im trying to figuer out how to seperate a line into a string and into an integer Like so:

String A = John F. Bush;
int B = 35;
And i cant seem to figuer out how to... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you mind showing us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

what about using c++11 and regex:

```
void fooRegex()
{
    std::string subject("James Bush 69");
    std::string result;

    std::regex re("[(0-9]+");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(subject, m, re);
    for(auto v: m)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```